# What's the easiest way to change the Windows proxy address using .NET code?

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, proxy

I found a code samples here:

http://sturla.simnet.is/post/2008/09/22/Enable-proxy-in-IE.aspx

But it's very complex and involves manipulating the Windows registry.

Is there an easier and less error-prone way of changing the proxy server address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to do this can be found [here](http://huddledmasses.org/setting-windows-internet-connection-proxy-from-c/), using the proper APIs rather than direct registry hacking